# Error while running MethylMix R package

Tags: r, r-package

I am trying to use MethylMix R package for EPIC array and Affymetrix gene expression array.

I have a question regarding the methylation data input. In the documentation it was mentioned that “Each of these three data sets are matrix objects with genes in the rows with unique rownames”
In my methylation data I have many methylation sites for each of the genes. To run MethylMix do you think I should take an average value of all methylation associated with a gene and then try to run MethylMix?

Earlier I have created 3 matrices with my data-sets where methylation data row names are not unique. However running MethylMix I am getting some error messages. (see below my error messages).

```
ClusterProbes(metcancer_M_100K, metnormal_M_100K, CorThreshold = 0.4)
Removing 0 probes with SNPs.
Clustering 3968 probes in CpG site clusters.
Error in { : 
  task 1 failed - "length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent"

MethylMixResults <- MethylMix(metcancer_M_100K, gecancer_M, metnormal_M_100K)
Found 25 samples with both methylation and expression data.
Correlating methylation data with gene expression...
Error in { : 
  task 1 failed - "variable lengths differ (found for 'METcancer[Genes[i], ]')"
```

Comment: would you please provide a dummy data and code that can replicate the issue? So that we can follow the data and code to have a look.

Comment: Here I am attaching a google drive link where I have shared the R code and the dummy data. https://drive.google.com/open?id=14o-4RJt0osXDw2sw6tAcdL7WhoWmWW_-